# Lots of worker_connections errors in nginx log

Tags: nginx

I have a website mounted on a VPS running with CloudFlare and I have been receiving many errors 520 (web server returns an unknown error) and 525 (SSL handshake failed). When reviewing the logs of my server I have noticed a lot of errors in nginx, the error is the following:

> 2019/07/03 15:24:25 [alert] 6782#0: 2048 worker_connections are not enough

This error appears in the log up to 17 times per minute. The nginx configuration file is the following:

```
 #user  nginx;
 worker_processes  1;

 #error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
 #error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
 #error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

 #pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

 include /etc/nginx/modules.conf.d/*.conf;

 events {
     worker_connections  2048;
 }


 http {
     include       mime.types;
     default_type  application/octet-stream;

     #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
     #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
     #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

     #access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

     sendfile        on;
     #tcp_nopush     on;

     #keepalive_timeout  0;
     keepalive_timeout  65;
     #tcp_nodelay        on;

     #gzip  on;
     #gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

     server_tokens off;

     include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
 }

 # override global parameters e.g. worker_rlimit_nofile
 include /etc/nginx/*global_params;
```

Initially the value of `worker_connections` was 1024 and I have raised it to 2048 but the problem remains the same.

The server has **4GB of RAM** and CPU with **4 cores 2.1GHz/core** and *nginx is working together with apache, configured by the Plesk panel*.

My question is, how do you recommend me to solve this problem? I searched in the web and I have not found an answer that convinces me. I am not sure of the recommended maximum values that I can set to `worker_processes` and`worker_connections` taking into account the characteristics of the server.

Comment: Please include your other nginx config is `/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the question asked before here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28265717/worker-connections-are-not-enough

The solution provided was to increase **worker_connections** to **20,000**.

```
events {
    worker_connections 20000;
}
```

I checked my config on a VERY busy server, and I can suggest another way. You can enable the **multi_accept** parameter. It will probably work better within your memory limits, as it will reuse connections whenever possible.

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    multi_accept        on;
}
```